# How cache OpenLDAP Meta database (for use with Websphere Application Server)?

Tags: ldap, openldap, cache, websphere, application-server

I have configured Meta database directory on OpenLDAP server for two different Active Diretories and it's work. But now I'd like set cache for this OpenLDAP, but I don't know how.

From my `slapd.conf`

```
database    meta
suffix      "dc=openldap,dc=domain,dc=com"
rootdn      "cn=Manager,dc=openldap,dc=domain,dc=com"
rootpw      pass
chase-referrals no
nretries    100
bind-timeout    1000000
```

Below after these lines are configuration for both AD.

I find code below, but when I use this or similar configuration which I found on the web and restart server with WAS where is LDAP configured as federated repositories then WAS not started (webserver yes). But when I check LDAP by Softerra LDAP browser then LDAP is accessible.

```
overlay       proxycache
proxyCache    bdb 100000 1 1000 1
proxyAttrset  0 mail telephonenumber
proxyTemplate (sn=) 0 3600
proxyTemplate (&(sn=)(givenName=)) 0 3600
cachesize     20
directory     /var/lib/ldap/meta
index         objectClass eq
index         cn,sn,uid,mail    pres,eq,sub
```

Is there any option how make OpenLDAP cache works? Thanks

Comment: I edited question for some additional information.